# Mysql manual insert

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am using MySQL as my database and developing with Spring Boot. In my application, I have a table where the `ID` value is generated using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`. However, when I try to manually insert data into the table, I encounter the warning `"Field 'id' doesn't have a default value."` How can I assign the `ID` value in this scenario while using MySQL and Spring Boot?

[image: Entity]

Comment: Can you open a terminal, connect to your database and run the command of `show create table <yourtable>;` and show us the results?

Comment: Based on info you provided I assume the table doesn't have AUTO_INCREMENT set on `id` field.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `stage` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify auto increment into your filed into database, that maybe helpful

Comment: I dont want to use auto increment becasue i want to use hibernate_sequence

Comment: You can use this instead 

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49241216/has-spring-boot-changed-the-way-auto-increment-of-ids-works-through-generatedva